# How to test private functions in jasmine

Tags: angularjs

I want to test my private function which is being called in a public function, How can I get access to code inside private functions.

```
For example:

var privateFunction = function() {
   this.flag = false;
}

this.$onInit= function() {  
   this.flag = true;
   privateFunction();
}
```

How can I test if the value of "flag" has been changed or not after the private function has been called?? I am trying to spyOn the privateFunction but its giving me method does not exist error.

Comment: You can temporarily make them public, test them, be happy when they pass then change them back to private. The word 'private' does actually mean something after all.

Comment: You don't test private functions. You test the side effect of the function. In this case, you'd test that after calling `$onInit()` that `flag` is `false`.